# Get all the list of folders and images inside a folder

Tags: php

The directories inside a gallery folder are dynamically created. And i am trying to access folders and corresponding images in it.As per now i accessed the folders but i am not getting images inside it.How to loop all images corressponding to a directory.
Please help me with this issue to fix it

```
 <?php
#default directory
$dir    = '../gallery/';
$files1 = scandir($dir);

#open a gallery directory 
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
#read all the directories inside a gallery folder
        while($file = readdir($handle)){

                        if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){
#get all images inside variable $file                           
                            echo '<img src="../gallery/'.$file.'/" border="0" height="100" width="150"/>';

                }    
        }


}

?>
```

Comment: Why not `glob()` http://in1.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: Yes i tried that but i am not able to make it in a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach(glob("../gallery/".'*') as $filename) {
    echo '<img src="../gallery/'.basename($filename).'/" border="0" height="100" width="150"/>';
}
```

Comment: Here i am able to retrieve only folders but not the images inside it.

Comment: The path is correct .http://localhost/test123/tamil/ here is my project is running .The gallery folder is inside test123